# Update nested array with Express and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express application with Mongoose. I have a model

```
var AttendeeSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    registered: Boolean
});

var EventSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    attendees : [AttendeeSchema],
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

The code for creating an event is:

```
router.route('/:event_id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Event.findById(req.params.event_id, function(err, event) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(event);
        });
    })

    .put(function(req, res) {
        Event.findById(req.params.event_id, function(err, event) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            event.name = req.body.name;
            event.description = req.body.description; 
            event.attendees: req.body.attendees;

            event.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'Event updated successfully!' });
            });

        });
    })
```

The code for updating an event is:

```
router.route('/:event_id')    
    .put(function(req, res) {
        Event.findById(req.params.event_id, function(err, event) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            event.name = req.body.name;
            event.description = req.body.description; 
            event.attendees: req.body.attendees;

            event.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'Event updated successfully!' });
            });

        });
    })
```

The problem is that events are being created successfully however when I try to update an event, it only updates the event name and description, but not changes to the attendees name or registered status. I also noticed that the version is not updated from "__v0" to "__v1"

Anyone some hints as to why I cannot update attendee specific information with the above code?

Comment: I assume the code `event.attendees: req.body.attendees;` is a typo and you meant it to be `event.attendees = req.body.attendees;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a `=` where you have a `:` ;)

```
event.attendees: req.body.attendees;
```

Comment: Oh boy, I have been looking at this for over 3 hours. You are fully correct, now it is updating perfectly. Thanks!!!